# Quadratic Equations with Complex Roots

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, complex-analysis

I don't understand what is the geometric ( or intuitive ) meaning of complex roots of a quadratic polynomial :

$ax^{2}+bx+c=0$

Can you help me ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The system

- $y=ax^2+bx+c$
- $y=0$

represents the intersection of a parabola with the $x$ axis and we can have three cases

- $2$ real solutions that is the parabola intersects the $x$ axis ($\Delta >0$)
- $1$ real solution that is the parabola is tangent to $x$ axis ($\Delta =0$)
- $2$ complex solutions that is the parabola does not intersect the $x$ axis ($\Delta <0$)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The geometric interpretation of complex roots is that  the parabola  does not intersect the x-axis.

It stays above the x-axis if $a$ is positive  and it stays below the x-axis if $a$ is negative.

Answer (score 0):

It means that $ax^2+bx+c$ gives $0$ when $x$ is a particular complex number.
since, $$x=\frac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$$
The discriminant $b^2-4ac$ can be less than $0$ equal to $0$ or greater than $0$
if the first case is there it means that we have a square root of negative number which is a complex number.
I think you can understand it if you have basic knowledge about complex numbers.