# Quadratic Equation does not pass through the x-axis

Tags: linear-algebra

If a quadratic equation does not pass through the x-axis, what can you say about its discriminant and the solutions of the quadratic equation?

Comment: The solutions are imaginary and the discriminant is smaller than 0.

Comment: Thank, I will. It is so cool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a quadratic function never crosses the $x$-axis, then it has no real roots or solutions. Hence, the discriminant must be negative.

$$\Delta = b^2-4ac$$

No real solution means

$$\Delta < 0$$

which is the same as

$$b^2-4ac < 0$$

meaning the solutions are imaginary/complex.

Answer (score 0):

Since we have not real solutions $\Delta=b^2-4ac<0$, more in detail we have two cases

- for $a>0$ and $b^2-4ac<0$ the equation $y=ax^2+bx+c$ represent a parabola concave up above the $x$-axis
- for $a<0$ and $b^2-4ac<0$ the equation $y=ax^2+bx+c$ represent a parabola concave down under the $x$-axis

Refer also to the raleted

- [Quadratic Equations with Complex Roots](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2777575/505767)