# For a given quadratic function, identify roots, vertex coordinates, and axis of symmetry

Tags: graphing-functions, quadratics, conic-sections

For each graph of quadratic functions shown, identify

A) $x^2-3x-4$
B) $2x^2+7x+3$

1) the solutions, or roots
2) coordinates of the vertex
3) equation of axis of symmetry

Comment: this is what wolfram alpha gives: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E2-3x-4 and https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2x%5E2%2B7x%2B3

Comment: @idea Not really helpful.

Comment: What did you try? Where are you stuck? Do you want roots of each? Do you want intersection points?

Comment: Welcome (again) to Math.SE! To expand upon a comment [your first question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3011283/409) received ...  The community here prefers/expects questions that include your thoughts, and/or an indication of where you got stuck. Such information helps answerers tailor responses to your skill level, without wasting anyone's time telling you what you already know. (It also helps convince people that you aren't simply trying to get them to do your homework for you.)

Comment: Your question mentions "each graph [...] shown", but shows no graph. You don't (yet) have enough reputation to post an image, but if you can link to an image (preferably hosted on a site such as [Imgur.com](http://imgur.com)), someone can add it to your question for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The roots of a quadratic equation are found where they give an output of $0$.

Take the first function as an example.

$$f(x) = x^2-3x-4$$

Let $f(x) = 0$.

$$x^2-3x-4 = 0$$

Notice most simple quadratics can be factored. $$x^2-3x-4 = (x-4)(x+1)$$

Now see what values of $x$ allow $f(x) = 0$.

When the function can’t be factored nicely, you can use the Quadratic Formula:

> $$x = \frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$$

To find the coordinates of the vertex $(h, k)$, use

> $$h = \frac{-b}{2a}$$
>
> $$k = c-\frac{b^2}{4a}$$

Most people solve for $h$ and plug the value as $x$ to find $y$ (which becomes $k$), but you can immediately use the formula too.

The axis of symmetry is at $x = h$, which you already find when solving for the vertex.

Comment: I disagree with giving complete answers to  elementary posts that show no effort, whereas hints may motivate the OP into solving the exercise.

Comment: I edited the post a bit to just give the basic idea.

Comment: Then +1 ........... !

Answer (score 4):

**Hints :**

For (1), in order to find the solutions/roots of the expressions given, you need to equate them to $0$ :

$$x^2-3x-4 = 0 $$

$$2x^2+7x-3 = 0$$

To solve the equations above, use the well-known quadratic formula.

For (2), recall that a quadratic polynomial is a parabola sketch graphically, thus its vertex lie on the extrema (maxima or minima) of the parabola. If you're familiar with differentiation, it's enough to find that extreme point by the derivative test. If you're not familiar with differentiation, then there is a stantard formula for the vertices, this is :

$$x_v  =-\frac{b}{2a}$$

for a quadratic polynomial of the form $ax^2 + bx + c = 0$.

Finally, for (3), since the graphs are parabolas and their vertices are found in (2), what would be the symmetry  axis ?

Comment: "If you're not familiar with differentiation" One can deduce this geometrically. The extremal point has to lie midway between the roots so it's the mean of the roots already found.

Comment: @Winther Well, I mentioned an alternative, which is a standard formula which can also be deduced without the use of differential calculus and is most often that not carried out in pre-calculus elementary algebra courses.

Answer (score 3):

**HINT**

We have that for $ax^2+bx+c=0$

> 1) The solutions, or roots

- use that $x_1,x_2=\frac{-b\pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$

> 2) Coordinates of the vertex

- use that $x_V=-\frac b{2a}$

> 3) equation of axis of symmetry

- see point $2$

For more details refer to [**Quadratic equation**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_equation).